# Type erasure of a closure that returns an async block

Tags: asynchronous, rust, closures

Consider the following closure that returns an async block:

```rust
|entity: &mut Entity| async move {
    entity.foo().await;
}
```

Is it possible to type erase and store this closure inside an enum, without specifying a generic type or lifetime on that enum? Consider the following MWE:

```rust
use std::future::Future;

struct Entity;
impl Entity {
    async fn foo(&mut self) {} 
}

fn main() {
    erase_and_store(|entity: &mut Entity| async move {
        entity.foo().await;
    });
}

fn erase_and_store<'a, C, F>(closure: C) -> Task where
    C: FnOnce(&'a mut Entity) -> F,
    F: Future<Output = ()> + 'a {
    
    Task::Variant(/* TODO convert closure to something that can be stored */)
}

enum Task {
    Variant(/* TODO store closure */)
}
```

I have tried a couple different approaches but it seems that even if I put everything behind boxed trait objects, I can not stop this generic lifetime `'a` from leaking through to my `Task` enum.

```rust
type AnyFuture<'a> = Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + 'a>;
type AnyClosure<'a> = Box<dyn FnOnce(&'a mut Entity) -> AnyFuture<'a>>;

enum Task {
    Variant(AnyClosure) // requires <'a>
}
```

Comment: (1) `Box`ing a future doesn't make it not borrow stuff. You can `Box` the result of `entity.foo` as much as you want, it'll still borrow `entity`. (2) `erase_and_store` doesn't return a `Box`ed anything, it returns an anonymous type that implements `Future`. Until `impl Trait` in closure return type position is stable, you can't name that type without generics.

Comment: @isaactfa correct me if I am wrong, but as soon as I put a generic on `Task`, an instance of `Task` can only hold one type of closure, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. But Chayim's HRTB with lifetime elision is actually a neat way to work around that.

Comment: [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=32fe5c48e826dffb12bba4921906f6ed) may be what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a higher-ranked lifetime:

```rust
type AnyFuture<'a> = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + 'a>>;
type AnyClosure = Box<dyn for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut Entity) -> AnyFuture<'a>>;
```

That can be elided:

```rust
type AnyFuture<'a> = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + 'a>>;
type AnyClosure = Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut Entity) -> AnyFuture<'_>>;
```